# Pass the value from a textarea to PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the text I enter in to a `textarea` to a PHP function.

```js
console.log($('#notes').val());
let report = {
  notes: $('#notes').val()
};
//this.userData.addMediaReport(report)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="notes" rows="4" cols="50">Lorem ipsum</textarea>
```

`console.log` returns `undefined`. Any ideas?

Comment: Unable to replicate (as you can see in the snippet I edited in to the question). Check the console for errors, and check that you're actually calling `val()` on the `textarea` *after* the user has entered a value. With regard to the point of sending the value to PHP, add a `form` to the HTML and submit it, or use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

put the $('#notes').val() code inside the form submit event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
      let report = {
        notes: $('#notes').val()
      };
    });
});
```

Make sure the textarea exists and contains the required value before it is accessed.

Comment: i use import $ from "jquery"; in typescript to call jquery

Comment: as long as it returns undefined before this it means it doesnt gets the value from textarea right?